# Trying to return each index of my array inside my UITableView

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to use the MVC model in my app. This is the first time I am using it as I am just learning iOS programming. There are several things you need to know to help me. First: I have a model called Home.swift inside this model I have an array and a function. "Home.swift":

```
class Home: NSObject {
  var content: [String] = [
    "Apple",
    "Door",
    "Evil",
    "Error",
]
func homeDisplayContent() -> String  {
    for var i = 0; i < 12; i++ {
        return content[i]
    }
}
}
```

Do I need an init in here, if so how would I implement it? Secondly, I have a View for my tableView. I don't think anything is wrong with my view. But just in case inside here I have my "HomeCell.swift":

```
    var homes: Home! {
    didSet{
        contentLabel.text = homes.homeContent()
    }
}
```

Lastly I have my view controller, "HomePageViewController.swift":

```
var homes: [Home]!



@IBOutlet weak var homeTableView: UITableView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.homeTableView.delegate = self
    self.homeTableView.dataSource = self
    homes = [Home()]
    self.homeTableView.reloadData()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("homeCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? HomeCell
    cell!.homes = homes[indexPath.row]

    return cell!
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.homes.count
}
```

What I want to do is be able to grab each index inside my array inside the Home.swift (My model) and present them in their own individual cells. I believe I need to create an array of Home objects but I am not sure how to go about doing this. Sorry for the block of text and for poor formatting (cannot for the life of me fix the first block of code) but I am really lost and have looked around on google and stackoverflow for awhile trying to figure out my problem with no luck. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You hardcoded the values in the model class itself. Then what are you doing ? Why is that loop which returns the first item every time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hard-coding the values in `contents` array. So you need to use the values from that array. There is no need to create multiple `Home` object in this case. You want something like:

**Home.swift**

```
class Home : NSObject
{
   var content: [String] = [
     "Apple",
     "Door",
     "Evil",
     "Error",
   ]

   func homeDisplayContent(atIndex : Int) -> String
   {
       return content[atIndex]
   }
}
```

**HomePageViewController.swift**

```
var home = Home()
@IBOutlet weak var homeTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.homeTableView.delegate   = self
    self.homeTableView.dataSource = self
    self.homeTableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("homeCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! HomeCell
    cell.contentLabel.text = home.homeDisplayContent(indexPath.row)
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return self.home.contents.count
}
```

Comment: Why don't we use my view cell (HomeCell.swift)? It ended up working with what you wrote me but I never really use my HomeCell.swift now

Comment: @Rcub3161: You are using it in the cell for row at index path. You are directly setting the label from that method.

Comment: Oh okay, just to clarify when I call home.homeDisplayContent(indexPath.row) it over rides the value in the didSet of my HomeCell.swift?

Comment: @Rcub3161: Actually that didSet will never work, since you are not setting the home property of your home cell.

Comment: I ended up adding inside my viewDidLoad() home = Home() in that case am I setting the property of my home cell?

Comment: @Rcub3161: The allocated home is the property of HomePageVC and you allocated it in the viewdidload, how can it affect the home cell ? I think you are missing some important concepts of OOPs. (Will try to explain it through an example: Consider home cell as your school and home page as your home. There are two empty glasses in your school and home (home property = glass). You are filling the glass located in your home with some water (Allocating the home property of home page). Now you tell me will there by any water in the glass you placed at your school ?) That is what you are asking here

Comment: Okay, I understand now. Thanks for all your help!